# Centered finite volume scheme for an advective term on an unstructured/irregular/non-uniform grid

Tags: pde, finite-volume, mesh, unstructured-mesh, grid

Consider the continuity equation

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x} = 0$$
$$\Phi = au + b\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$

Suppose I want to solve the above using centered finite volumes. Below, $U_j \approx \overline{u}_j$ where $\overline{u}_j$ is the spatial average value of $u$ in a finite volume. $\Phi_{i+1/2}$ and $\Phi_{i-1/2}$ are the fluxes at the edges of the finite volume, and $\Delta x_i$ is the thickness of the the volume.

$$\frac{\partial U_j}{\partial t} = -\frac{\Phi_{i+1/2} - \Phi_{i-1/2}}{\Delta x_i}$$

For a structured grid, I can use the following centered approximation for the fluxes

$$\Phi_{i+1/2} = a_{j+1/2}\frac{U_{j+1} + U_{j}}{2} + b_{j+1/2}\frac{U_{j+1} - U_{j}}{\frac{1}{2}\Delta x_{j+1} + \frac{1}{2}\Delta x_{j}}$$

For the advective term above, I have approximated $U_{j+1/2}$ as

$$U_{j+1/2} = \frac{U_{j+1} + U_{j}}{2}$$

**My question is what is a more general centered approximation of $U_{j+1/2}$ for an unstructured grid?** One possibility is to linearly interpolate to $U_{j+1/2}$ between the center of the finite volumes containing $U_{j+1}$ and $U_{j}$. The result is

$$U_{j+1/2} = \frac{U_{j+1} \Delta x_j + U_{j} \Delta x_{j+1}}{\Delta x_{j+1} + \Delta x_{j}} \tag{1}$$

A reference equation in a textbook would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You are treating the values of $U$ as if they were point values at the cell center, rather than cell averages.  This is fine as long as you only want 2nd order accuracy, since the midpoint approximates the average to 2nd order.

Comment: Ferziger, Peric & Street (2020) provide references to other schemes. See https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-99693-6_4.
Another book is Pulliam & Zingg (2014) - https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-05053-9.